# Remote debugger is saying object is null, but its not?

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug a `UWP` application written in `C#` using `Visual Studio 2017`. I have the application running with the debugger attached and the corresponding `PDB` symbol files loaded, I think (taken from the `\bin\x64\Release` folder).

When I hit the third break point (third red line) the debugger is reporting that my object is null... but the object really isn't null and the code continues to run correctly... It even reached the yellow line, the next executing line..

[image]

Any ideas on how to resolve this so I can observe the properties of the object?

Comment: I know that such things can happen even when debugging local processes, so it's not just a remote debugger issue, I'd say.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 is a bit flaky when it comes to runtime peeks.  I've seen all sorts of odd things, including a persistent error regarding the tooltip that presents the value.  That one makes you completely restart the debug session.

Comment: Open up the project that contains the source code and run the application in *debug* mode if you want to be able to step through the code.

Comment: @mm8 you can step through code just fine in release mode. The issue seems to be a bug in which VS17 is unable to load the object in remote debug session.

Comment: The code is optimized in release mode so stepping through the code line by line may give unexpected results. This is not a bug in VS.